# SSMS 19 prompts for login when already connected to MI

Tags: ssms-19

I'm connected to an Azure Managed Instance in SSMS 19 and am navigating stored procs.  If I right-click a sproc and select modify, I'm prompted for my credentials.  This ONLY happens in SSMS 19;  SSMS 18 doesn't prompt me when I've already connected to the server. Is this a bug in 19, or is there a property I can change so it stops prompting me when I've obviously already connected to the server?